# multiple openfires on a single ip

Tags: xmpp, openfire

would you please tell me how to configure two openfires on a single IP. I have used different ports to the 2 openfire,but there are list of ports in each openfire server for multiple operations (i.e. ex:7070 port is to http bind,9090 for admin console.).and openfire creates list of tables(tablenames starts with "of". ex:ofxxxx).these generated table names are fixed.but here for the 2 openfires, I want to maintain separate set of tables and I don't want to mesh up the CRUD oprations of each openfire server.(I need 2 openfire servers in two different scenarios on my pc with single schema.)

If any one have Idea in this scenario,Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, you need to ensure that everything is using different ports, and additionally you need to create a separate database for the second instance of Openfire. This will ensure that they won't conflict with each other.

You can edit the port for http-bind in the Openfire admin console `Server>Server Settings>HTTP Binding`

The other ports can be adjusted from `Server>Server Manager>Server Information` scroll down to "server ports" and edit the values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is worth considering installing visualization software, which allows you to run two 'servers' on one piece of hardware. That way, you can have dedicated resources for each Openfire instance, and, as a bonus, you can have duplicate configuration settings. That will make things easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run XMPP services on two separate domains, but on one machine, with each domain having it's own list of users & buddy rosters?

To do this on Openfire, you would need to install two instances of the software.

ie. `/opt/openfire` and `/opt/openfire2`).

Rename `/opt/openfire2/bin/openfire` to `openfire2`.

Edit the `/opt/openfire2/conf/openfire.xml` file to change the console ports from `9090 / 9091` to something like `9098 / 9099`.

Symlink `/opt/openfire2/bin/openfire2` to `/etc/init.d/openfire2` (`sudo  ln -s /opt/openfire_2/bin/openfire_2 /etc/init.d/`)

Start the 2nd openfire service (`sudo service openfire2 start`).

Go to `localhost:9098` and start setting up the 2nd instance on a separate domain. **Be sure to use a separate mysql DB**.

If your server only has one IP address, **be sure to change the XMPP port on the 2nd instance to something other than 5222**.

If your server has more than one IP address, you can uncomment the  section in openfire.xml to specify the two instances to listen on separate interfaces/IP addresses.

If you go this route, you can leave the console and XMPP ports set to default.

Or alternately, you could ditch openfire and use ejabberd instead - it supports serving multiple domains (with separate DBs / user accounts / rosters) from a single server instance & IP address. However, Openfire is better documented and has a much more polished admin interface. Also, ejabberd lacks an RTP proxy plugin, and the jinglenodes plugin is an enormous pain in the ass to set up on it.

Comment: Could you add some [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), such as a list? Its a bit hard to read at the moment.